# How to avoid problems introduced by @types packages with patch level increase that introduces breaking change?

Tags: angular, typescript, package.json, typescript-types

I realized that a Jenkins build of our Angular app is broken. We got the following error message.:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angular2-hotkeys/lib/hotkeys.service.d.ts:9:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MousetrapInstance'.

9     mousetrap: MousetrapInstance;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then problem is the [following breaking change](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/3b9164015e3baaba1adc4b147c602075649219f7#r42720295) in [`@types/mousetrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mousetrap) from:

```
export const mousetrap: MousetrapInstance;
```

to:

```
export const mousetrap: Mousetrap.MousetrapInstance;
```

In [angular2-hotkeys](https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys) [`package.json`](https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys/blob/master/package.json), the dependencies are defined as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
     "mousetrap": "^1.6.0",
     "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.0"
 },
```

What is the correct NPM way to avoid this version problem?

Comment: Maybe contribute to angular2-hotkeys and fix their package.json

Comment: Actually there is https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys/pull/135 , but it's still open. But your question is still valid, maybe there is a way to override dependencies locally via npm

Answer (score -1):

You cannot guarantee the package version used with `package.json`, even if you specify an exact match (without the `^`) because there may be dependencies requiring another version.

The only way to be sure that the version in your computer, and the version in the CI are the same is to also commit the `package-lock.json` file.